# Get single row based on the date and another column value in mysql table

Tags: mysql, select

I guess I am making some silly mistake in the query or I am totally wrong.
Following is my table

```
type | amount |date
  EUR|      50|2017-09-18 11:43:51
  USD|      35|2017-09-18 11:43:51
  EUR|      80|2017-09-10 11:43:51
```

Expected output is as follows:

```
type | amount |date
  EUR|      50|2017-09-18 11:43:51
  USD|      35|2017-09-18 11:43:51
```

friends kindly help me.

Comment: Please post your query and/or explain the logic you used to arrive at the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT type, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY type
) t2
    ON t1.type = t2.type AND
       t1.date = t2.max_date
```